# laravel and graphql (client): multi-part upload of file

Tags: laravel, graphql

Would like to use Laravel to perform a file upload using Graphql.

The curl version of the mutation looks like:

```bash
curl "https://mygraphql" \
  -F operations='{ \
    "query": "mutation ($file: Upload!) { my_aws_bucket { uploadFile(file: $file) { Key, Location } } }", \
    "variables":{"file": null} \
    }' \
  -F map='{ "0": ["variables.file"] }' \
  -F 0=@example.jpg
```

Laravel documentation mentions for [multi-part requests](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#multi-part-requests):

```
$response = Http::attach(
    'attachment', file_get_contents('photo.jpg'), 'photo.jpg'
)->post('http://example.com/attachments');
```

Unclear to me how to convert the curl request to a Laravel equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in my original attempt, here's what works for me:

```
$response = Http::attach(
    'myfile', file_get_contents('example.jpg'), 'example.jpg'
)->post('https://mygraphql', [
  'operations' => '"query": "mutation ($file: Upload!) { my_aws_bucket { uploadFile(file: $file) { Key, Location } } }", "variables":{"file": null}  }',
  'map' => '{ "myfile": ["variables.file"] }'
]);
```